# Issue with incorrect calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, acrobat

```
    var spring = this.getField("Calibration_Spring_Value_low").value;
    if (event.value > (spring + .2) || event.value < spring - .2) {
        event.rc = false
        app.alert("Value is out of range");
        }
```

The above snippet is for a Field validation for a data form in Adobe Acrobat.  When I run it as written, it works works fine comparing the event value to +/- .2 of the Spring value.  However when I put in a value of 19.9 for the "spring" value, the form will reject a value of 20.1.   This appears to be the only set of values this fails for.

I managed to put a bandaid on it by changing the statement to this

```
if (event.value >= (spring + .3) || event.value  < spring -.2) {
```

Is there any insight into why this is preforming this way, and how I can correctly fix to the problem and be certain it will preform correctly for all inputted values?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with brackets?

```
if (event.value > (spring + .2) || event.value < (spring - .2)) {
```

Comment: Is spring guaranteed to be an integer? If not, "20.1"-.2 might give confusing results...